# Explicitly Managing WiFi Power Consumption in Android

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

**Background**

I'm developing a research application that runs on Android phones. In short, the application runs so long as the phone is on and periodically takes information from many components and sensors on the phone. The application is to disturb the user as little as possible. That being said, it's draining the battery far too quickly and forces the user to recharge every day. This simply won't do.

To try and figure out how to improve the situation, a colleague also working on the application let the application run for a long period of time and noticed that the biggest battery hog is WiFi. My current idea is to manually shut off WiFi when it's not in use in an attempt to save power. AFAIK, Android uses PSM for WiFi to accomplish this to some end, but it doesn't seem to be enough.

**Problem**

Is there a way to "ramp up" Android's PSM? Or, [if there is not as this question suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514123/android-wifi-power-question), is there any way that I can safely turn WiFi on and off without adversely affecting the user? I.e., is there a way to tell which applications are using WiFi and turn it off when none are? Do standard applications - such as the web browser and email clients - use [WiFi locks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html) to prevent WiFi from being turned off when they are working?

Any advice on where to start in solving this problem are greatly appreciated. Information on how Android's PSM works, how long it takes for it to take effect, or any information relevant to the problem are very welcome.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to "ramp up" Android's PSM?

Not via the Android SDK.

> I.e., is there a way to tell which applications are using WiFi and turn it off when none are?

The OS does this already.

> Do standard applications - such as the web browser and email clients - use WiFi locks to prevent WiFi from being turned off when they are working?

Some probably do. You are welcome to [search the Android source code](http://www.google.com/codesearch#/&exact_package=android) and find out. Of course, bear in mind that there are no "standard applications" -- I presume you are thinking of the ones that are part of the Android open source project.

> Any advice on where to start in solving this problem are greatly appreciated.

Find out where in your own code you are being inefficient, specifically here:

> the application runs so long as the phone is on and periodically takes information from many components and sensors on the phone.

If the device behaves fine when your code is not running, and the device does not behave fine when your code is running, then the problem lies in your code. Conversely, if the device does not behave fine even when your code is not running, then something else is afoot (device defect, firmware defect, rogue application, etc.), but it probably has nothing to do with StackOverflow.

Comment: I completely understand it is my code that is draining the power; it's the nature of the application that I'm running _and_ I know the largest energy hogs in the application. The problem is that I would like to drain _less_ power from those parts - in particular, those related to WiFi - and was looking for advice related to them.

Comment: @kanov-baekonfat: Other than to use WiFi less yourself, there is not much you can do. It seems strange that an app that "periodically takes information from many components and sensors on the phone" would consume so much WiFi. Applications of this nature should be storing the data locally and only uploading on occasion (e.g., once every few hours), and a minute's use of WiFi every now and then will not consume much power.

Comment: It doesn't consume much WiFi per use, but because the period can be relatively small it can potentially use it often. Anyway, after doing more research on the problem I have found that the only thing I can do is to make my program more efficient or change the period. Thanks for your help.